# Azure AD - using SP to create an app registration and its credentials

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

So here is the thing. I have a bunch of scripts that during the initial environment setup create an app registration in Azure, its ServicePrincipal, and finally sets a certificate as a key. **Everything works just fine while I'm logged in as a user with Global Admin role**.

Now, for the sake of automation, I need to do the same but **using a ServicePrincipal rather than my user's account**. The idea is to use it to create/delete app registrations and rotate their keys. Consider it some sort of master SP. So I've created one, and granted it next permissions -

```
Microsoft Graph - Application Permission: "Read directory data"
Microsoft Graph - Application Permission: "Read and write directory data"
Windows Azure Active Directory - Application Permission: "Read directory data"
Windows Azure Active Directory - Application Permission: "Read and write directory data"
```

The SP has been assigned with **Owner role** for a given subscription.

My automation script executes next commands -

```
Get-AzureRmADApplication
New-AzureRmADApplication
New-AzureRmADAppCredential
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal
```

Powershell version is 5.1
    AzureRM.Resources module version is 6.1.0

Here is the way I set the account in the script -

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "Master_SP_Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Master_SP_AppId", $secpasswd)
Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant "***" -Subscription "***" -Credential $creds
Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId *** -TenantId ***
```

And here is what I'm getting right now -

- Get-AzureRmADApplication - executes just fine
- New-AzureRmADApplication - throws **Resource not found for the segment 'me'**
- New-AzureRmADAppCredential - have tried the command for an existing app, and it fails with **Insufficient privileges to complete the operation**
- New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal - have tried the command for an existing app, throws **Resource not found for the segment 'me'**

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting

> Resource not found for the segment 'me'

is because when you get an insufficient privileges request the graph API navigates to the `/me` endpoint on the Graph API however Service Principals do not have this endpoint available to them.

As for the the

> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

problem. I have a Service Principal with permission to create Applications. The permission you're looking for is on the Graph API Permission blade is

[image: App Permission]

```
Manage Apps that this app creates or owns
```

This Permission allows the service principal to create applications and manage the ones it's created. This is an admin permission so you'll need to press the `Grant Permissions` button to enable this.

To see what permissions have been granted by users and admins, navigate to the Enterprise Application for the app and select the Permissions blade. Granted permissions are listed here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll check it out and get back to u

Comment: It's working! Thank you! Another question I've got right away, how to make it work for the existing apps that a given SP hasn't created?

Comment: The way I achieve this is I have made the Service Principal the owner on the apps I want it to be able to manage. This is to give it the least amount of permissions as I don't want it to control all the applications in my AAD. To achieve this I used the `Add-AzureADApplicationOwner` cmdlet in the [Azure AD Powershell Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/Add-AzureADApplicationOwner?view=azureadps-2.0). This works because the permission is 

**Creates or Owns**

Comment: Got it... so there is no other way than using Add-AzureADApplicationOwner? like another permission that would grant the access to the apps that the SP doesn't own?

Comment: If Read and Write Directory Data isn't working for you I can't see another permission that could enable it. The only thing you could try is giving your service principal the role of Application Administrator however I'd advise to open a new question as it's too long an answer to have in a comment

Comment: Will do. On last thing - I've tried as you've suggested Add-AzureADApplicationOwner command, and it fails with the next error - "The reference target 'Application_***' of type 'Application' is invalid for the 'owners' reference." Any thoughts?

Comment: You can't add an application to be an owner you have to add the Service Prinicpal so grab the service principal for the application and then apply it's object id

Comment: Work like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177274/discussion-between-phil-peters-and-kiryl-z).